# Trouble getting return type from string builder in final method for word scramble game

Tags: java, methods, stringbuilder, return-type

I have to make a word scrambler "game" and I have all the methods I need to use. I still need to put code in the main method for asking users guess and using .equals to see if its the right word. That's not a problem. I'm running into an issue on my scrambleWord(word) method. I used string builder and cannot figure out how to return. The code looks good and builds but says there is an error. Can anyone help? This is my code as of now.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

 /**
 *
 * @author Brian2
 */
 public class Project3 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    //Shuffle s = new Shuffle();
      //  s.shuffle("hello");

    String[] words = createListOfWords();
    String word = chooseRandomWord(words);
    String scrambledWord = scrambleWord(word);
    System.out.println(scrambledWord);

    /* code for asking userers guess
    *
    *use .equals
    *
    *
    */

}
double[] wordList = new double[65573];

private static String[] createListOfWords() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("wordlist.txt"));
    String str;

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        list.add(str);
    }

    String[] stringArr = list.toArray(new String[0]);

    // test to see if array stored--System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringArr));
    return stringArr;

}

/**
 *
 * @param words
 * @return
 */
private static String chooseRandomWord(String[] words) {

    int index = new Random().nextInt(words.length);

    String word = words[index];

    return word;
}

private static String scrambleWord(String word) {

    char[] charArray = word.toCharArray();



        List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<>();

        StringBuilder scrambledWord = new StringBuilder(word.length());

            int randPicker = (int) (Math.random() * characters.size());
    StringBuilder append = scrambledWord.append(characters.remove(randPicker));




/*for (int i = charArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) { 
 int j = ((int)(Math.random())(i + 1));

 double scrambledWord = charArray[i];
 charArray[i] = charArray[j];
 charArray[j] = (char) scrambledWord;
 }*/

return scrambledWord.toString() ;
/*This method should take a word as an argument, and return the 
 same word, except scrambled. In order to scramble a word, convert 
 it to an array of chars, like this:*/
    //char[] charArray = word.toCharArray();

 }

  }
```

Comment: *"The code looks good and builds but says there is an error."* What error does it say there is?

Comment: it said there was an error in the main method at scrambleWord but using the suggestion below it solved it and returned what i needed.

Comment: If you're referring to the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` (which I had to recreate by running your code and creating my own `wordlist.txt`, since you provided neither the stack trace nor a minimal compilable example), look at your stack trace. It tells you exactly where the error is. In your case it clearly identifies your call to `.remove(...)` in `scrambleWord`, which is [documented as throwing that if the index is out of range](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)). Please follow [these guidelines](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/616460).

Comment: In other words; post relevant information and put a minimal amount of effort into research first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never added any characters into your `List` in `scrambleWord`. I would use [`Collections.shuffle(List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) and something like

```
private static String scrambleWord(String word) {
    List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<>();
    for (char ch : word.toCharArray()) {
        characters.add(ch);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(characters);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char ch : characters) {
        sb.append(ch);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Copy + paste, homework done, no problem solving skills learned, another vampire with a full belly.